# Azure Function: Remove double data in JSON from two many to many relationships to one table

Tags: c#, sql, json, azure-functions

The problem is that i've two many to many tables to one table and it gives me alot of double data that I want to delete in the JSON. Also the Ingredients and the Conditions are in a list so that they will show the list for every Ingredient. Also the same recipes will show 10 times after each other.

This is a part of my Function:

```
 List<JuiceIt> types = new List<JuiceIt>();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    command.Connection = connection;
                    String sql = "SELECT recipes.Name AS Name, recipes.Description AS Description, Ingredients.ingredient AS Ingredients, condition.condition AS Condition FROM recipes, Ingredients, RecipeIngredient, condition, RecipeCondition Where recipes.id = RecipeIngredient.RecipeId AND Ingredients.id = RecipeIngredient.IngredientId AND recipes.id = RecipeCondition.RecipeId AND condition.id = RecipeCondition.ConditionId ORDER BY Name;";
                    command.CommandText = sql;
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();


                    List<string> IngredientList = new List<string>();
                    List<string> ConditionList = new List<string>();
                    JuiceIt type = new JuiceIt();
                    string PrevName = type.Name;
                    while (reader.Read())
                        {

                        if (PrevName == type.Name)
                        {
                            JuiceIt newType = new JuiceIt();
                            types.Add(newType);
                            newType.Name = reader["Name"].ToString();
                            newType.Description = reader["Description"].ToString();
                            newType.Ingredients = IngredientList;
                            IngredientList.Add(reader["Ingredients"].ToString());
                            newType.Condition = ConditionList;
                            newType.Condition.Add(reader["Condition"].ToString());
                            PrevName = type.Name;
                            type = newType;
                        }
                        else
                         {
                            ConditionList = new List<string>();
                            IngredientList = new List<string>();
                            type.Condition = ConditionList;
                            type.Ingredients = IngredientList;
                            ConditionList.Add(reader["Condition"].ToString());
                            IngredientList.Add(reader["Ingredients"].ToString());
                            PrevName = type.Name;
                            type = type;
                        }
                    }



                }
            }
```

The model:

```
namespace JuiceItFunction.model
{
    class JuiceIt
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("description")]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("ingredients")]
        public List<string> Ingredients { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("condition")]
        public List<string> Condition { get; set; }

    }
}
```

A small part of the JSON that i've generated:

```
[
{
    "name": "All C",
    "description": "Peel the citrus fruits. Add the mint first, then add the ingredients through the juicer. Serve immediately and enjoy the taste. ",
    "ingredients": [
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "Beet"
    ],
    "condition": [
        "Immunity",
        "Immunity",
        "Immunity",
        "Autoimmune",
        "Autoimmune",
        "Autoimmune",
        "Autoimmune",
        "Cancer",
        "Cancer",
        "Cancer",
        "Cancer",
        "GI",
        "GI",
        "GI",
        "GI",
        "Heart Disease",
        "Heart Disease",
        "Heart Disease",
        "Heart Disease",
        "High Cholesterol",
        "High Cholesterol",
        "High Cholesterol",
        "High Cholesterol",
        "Skin",
        "Skin",
        "Skin",
        "Skin",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Arthritis",
        "Arthritis",
        "Arthritis",
        "Arthritis",
        "Allergies",
        "Allergies",
        "Allergies",
        "Allergies",
        "Thyroid",
        "Thyroid",
        "Thyroid",
        "Thyroid",
        "Cancer"
    ]
},
{
    "name": "All C",
    "description": "Peel the citrus fruits. Add the mint first, then add the ingredients through the juicer. Serve immediately and enjoy the taste. ",
    "ingredients": [
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "GrapeFruit",
        "Orange",
        "Lemon",
        "Mint",
        "Beet"
    ],
    "condition": [
        "Immunity",
        "Immunity",
        "Immunity",
        "Autoimmune",
        "Autoimmune",
        "Autoimmune",
        "Autoimmune",
        "Cancer",
        "Cancer",
        "Cancer",
        "Cancer",
        "GI",
        "GI",
        "GI",
        "GI",
        "Heart Disease",
        "Heart Disease",
        "Heart Disease",
        "Heart Disease",
        "High Cholesterol",
        "High Cholesterol",
        "High Cholesterol",
        "High Cholesterol",
        "Skin",
        "Skin",
        "Skin",
        "Skin",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Stroke",
        "Arthritis",
        "Arthritis",
        "Arthritis",
        "Arthritis",
        "Allergies",
        "Allergies",
        "Allergies",
        "Allergies",
        "Thyroid",
        "Thyroid",
        "Thyroid",
        "Thyroid",
        "Cancer"
    ]
},
```

Here is my database diagram:

[image: Database]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;

type.Condition = ConditionList.Distinct().ToList();
type.Ingredients = IngredientList.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: If I add that I get the error. Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'.

Comment: Edited. The error is explaining the C# doesn't know how to convert an IEnumerable<string> (which is the output type of the Distinct() method) into a List<string>, which is what you're using in your code. Adding the .ToList() method give C# a way to convert the IEnumerable to a List.

Comment: That worked for me. BUT. now there's one problem left... Now I see the same recipes multiple times. How can I solve this? Maybe I can take from every recipe the last one in the JSON in some way?